# TypeError : as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given in Django

Tags: django

I am getting an error:

> TypeError at /logout/ as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

urls.py

```
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
```

Comment: How do you call this logout view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

auth_views.LogoutView.as_view()

Comment: add more details please